# Looping callback method inside another another callback method

Tags: java, methods, callback

I have the below method in java

```
@Override
public void getResponse(String res) {
app.send("1",new Controller.CallbackMessage(){
 //
  @Override
   public void responseMessage(String ms) {
    Log.d("trim_log", "1 entered");
});

}
```

what i want to loop 3 times(dynamic , it might be more) and to produce like below code using for loop

```
@Override
public void getResponse(String res) {
    app.send("1",new Controller.CallbackMessage(){
            //
        @Override
   public void responseMessage(String ms) {
        Log.d("trim_log", "1 entered");
        //
        app.send("2",new Controller.CallbackMessage(){
                //
            @Override
   public void responseMessage(String ms) {
            Log.d("trim_log", "2 entered");
            //
            app.send("3",new Controller.CallbackMessage(){
                    //
                @Override
   public void responseMessage(String ms) {
                Log.d("trim_log", "3 entered");
            });
        });
    });

}
```

you can see how the callback nested in each callback ,please help.

Comment: read about publisher subscriber pattern in java or you can have event-driven architecture .... it will suit your above requirement...

Comment: can you help with a sample code or something please ?